# Compact, infinite, invariant set on shift space.

Tags: ergodic-theory

Let $X \subset \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a compact, infinite, shift invariant set. Does $X$ contains a non-periodic point?.

My attempt: I was trying to construct a non-periodic point, given that we have orbits of randomly large periods inside $X$, but without arriving at anything interesting. My second idea was to construct somehow a open family for $X$, use the fact that $X$ is compact and extract a finite subfamily to conclude that the period of any point in $X$ is bounded by some constant, arriving to a contradiction ($X$ must be infinite)

Comment: @JohnB what you're suggesting won't work. For a finite string $w$, let $f(w)$ denote the infinite string with period $w$. The sequence $f(011),f(01011),f(0101011),f(010101011),\dots$ converges to $01010101\dots$, a periodic sequence. You definitely need to use the "shift-invariant" hypothesis in the problem statement. In the setting I described, you can shift all of the strings to start with $11$ so that the sequence will converge to $110101010101\dots$ which is not periodic.

Comment: In fact, as @mathworker21 said, they can converge to a periodic point. It's a bit long (to write down), but I showed that if there exist such sequence converging to a periodic point, then it is possible to  construct a non-periodic point that belongs to the compact set.

Comment: @Rhcpy99 so you solved the problem?

Comment: That's true. That never happened to me before (to solve a question before anyone in stack exchange) I have to close the question, right?

Comment: @Rhcpy99 you can post your solution below. (also, if you start with (at symbol)mathworker21, ill get a notification that you commented to me)

Comment: @mathworker21 Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Rhcpy99 want to post your solution?